# Socket.io client connects to server but instantly triggers the "connect_error" event and continuous reconnecting

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

The problem is that the socket.io client establishes a connection to the server (behind nginx reverse proxy) but the "connect_error" callback is instantly triggered on the client. On localhost the server did just fine but on the server it doesn't establish a proper connection.

**Additional Information:**

The socket.io server and reverse proxy are both dockerized. The TCP Handshake seems to work but the problem is that the "connect_error" callback is instantly accessed and the client starts reconnecting over and over again.

**Client Code:**

```
io = require("socket.io-client");

const socket = io.connect("https://api.messboot.at/socket.io", {
  transports: ["websocket"],
});

socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
  console.log("connection error!");
  console.log(error);
});
```

**Socket.io Server Code:**

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';
import {
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { GpsDTO } from '@dto/gps.dto';
import { GpsService } from '@services/gps/gps.service';

interface GpsMessage {
  timestamp_executed: string;
  session_id: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  speed: number;
  accuracy: number;
}

@WebSocketGateway(8000, {
  transport: ['websocket'],
  allowUpgrades: false,
  //namespace: '/socket.io/gps',
})
export class GPSGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  constructor(private service: GpsService) {}
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('WebsocketGateway');

  @WebSocketServer() wss: Server;

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Initialized:');
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client with id: ${client.id} connected!`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client with id: ${client.id} disconnected!`);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('to_server')
  handleMessage(@MessageBody() message: GpsMessage): void {
    this.wss.emit('from_server', message);
    const gps_data: GpsMessage = {
      timestamp_executed: message.timestamp_executed,
      session_id: message.session_id,
      latitude: message.latitude,
      longitude: message.longitude,
      speed: message.speed,
      accuracy: message.accuracy,
    };

    this.service.saveGpsDto(GpsDTO.from(gps_data));
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

**Server Logs:**

```
[Nest] 30   - 05/12/2021, 8:39:49 AM   [WebsocketGateway] Client with id: FKwbAKhcTWvBFrPAAABM connected!
```

***Does anyone know what the problem could be?***

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the client and server were not compatible, because the nestjs dependencies of socket.io depend on version 2.x.x of socket.io and the client (version 3 of socket.io) tried reconnecting over and over again but there was no clear sign why this would happen until I found an issue referring to that on Github. Nestjs had announced to support socket.io version 3 in their next major release (v 8) until then there is an adapter code you can use: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5676